# Can't use oracle managed driver in ASP.NET Core 1 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to move from ASP.NET Core RC1 to 1.0.0-preview2 but having problems using Oracle managed driver that was working before. I am getting a following error trying to create a new OracleConnection:

> Error CS0012 The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Ludens.Data..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>   16    Active

Here is a code where I use it:

```
using System;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Ludens.Common;
using System.Data;

namespace Ludens.Data
{
  public class LegacyContext : IDisposable
  {
    public IDbConnection Connection { get; }

    public LegacyContext(IOptions<LudensSettings> options)
    {
      var appSettings = options.Value;
      Connection = new OracleConnection(appSettings.Oracle.Connection);
      Connection.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      Connection.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Also here is my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Dapper": "1.50.0",
    "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess": "12.1.24160419",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Ludens.Common": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "net451"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have a feeling that I incorrectly specify dependencies but figure out what I am missing. Please advice.

Comment: Oracle does not yet announce .NET Core support, and Microsoft plans to add support later. Currently you can only buy DevArt's library to connect if you want to target netcoreapp1.0

Comment: Thank for quick response @LexLi, microsoft is trying to better but always something is missing :)

Comment: waiting with baited breath on that.  Any idea how to write a connector for java?  Maybe I can contribute something to the .net core project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was noted by @LexLi Oracle doesn't yet support .net core so you won't be able to target netcoreapp1.0.

However, if you're only targeting windows platform, you can simply target a supported .net framework:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": { }
}
```

This will at least allow you to develop in .net core, and when Oracle support does arrive, upgrading should just be a matter of amending your project.json.

Note, if you want to use the Entity Framework 7 against Oracle, this still won't work, you'll need to wait for a supported library.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that DbConnection error, too.
What worked for me is adding the reference to System.Data, which basically the error tells you to do.
It took me a while to figure it out, too.

So in short:

- Right click on "References" of your project.
- Click "Add Reference..."
- From .NET Framework 4.6.1 (or similar), select "System.Data" and click OK.
- VS will process the changes and the errors will disappear.